# will php header location change before the document is loaded stop search crawlers?

Tags: php, search, robots.txt

By requiring users to have a session set and if it is not redirecting them using php header, am I securely keeping search engine crawlers from seeing my page content?

I don't see how they would but I want to be positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good crawlers will follow the redirect and not see the page content. Bad bots will still crawl the page. That is why you should always end execution of the script using [`exit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after sending out your redirect headers.

```
header('Location: /login.php');
exit();
```

Comment: after the header("Location") call or at the end of the page?

Comment: Immediately after the `header("Location")` call